# JMS Serializer xml deserialization type

Tags: php, xml, deserialization, jmsserializerbundle

I've got xml like this.

```
<projects>
    <entry key="project"></entry>
    <entry key="project"></entry> 
    <entry key="project"></entry>
</projects>
```

And entity

```
class Project
{
    const ENCODING = 'UTF-8';

    /**
     * @var integer
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @var array(\ACme\ProjectBundle\Entity\Project)
     * @JMS\Type("array<Acme\ProjectBundle\Entity\Project>")
     * @JMS\XmlList(entry="projects")
     */
    protected $projects;
}
```

I'm trying to deserialize it using JMS serializer like that:

```
  return $this->serializer->deserialize($rawXml, 'array<Acme\ProjectBundle\Entity\Project>', 'xml');
```

But I'm still getting error message:

> `The array type must be specified either as "array<T>", or "array<K,V>".`

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
ArrayCollection<Acme\ProjectBundle\Entity\Project>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it will work this way :

```
class Projects
{
    /**
     * @JMS\Type("array<Acme\ProjectBundle\Entity\Project>")
     * @JMS\XmlList(entry="entry")
     */
    protected $entries;
}
class Project
{
    /**
     * @JMS\Type("string")
     * @JMS\XmlAttribute
     */
    protected $key;
}
```